# NextJS app needs to rebuild after file upload to public folder

Tags: docker, file-upload, next.js, production

I'm looking for solutions where I need to return newly uploaded files on a NextJS app.

Currently, it seems to need to run "next build" / "next start" to return the files instead of HTTP 404.

This app is deployed using docker and my current solution is to restart the container (in which it will re-run "npm run build" and "npm run start").

Thanks for you help.

Comment: do you upload your files to `public` folder?

Comment: @felixmosh yes but I just realised I should not.